# How to add some parameters to a JSON request?

Tags: ios, json, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

Usually, to download a JSON, I use AFNetworking creating a singleton with this code

```
- (void)getJSON {
    NSURLRequest * request =
    [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
     [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://URL"]];

    AFJSONRequestOperation * operation =
    [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
     success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {

         NSArray * js = JSON;
         [_delegate dati:js];

         NSArray * paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
         NSString * filePath = [[paths lastObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"downloaded.json"];

         NSData * data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:JSON
                                                         options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted
                                                           error:NULL];
         [data writeToFile:filePath
                atomically:YES];

     }];

    [operation start];
}
```

and calling this code in View Controller

```
[[DataManager sharedClass] getJSON];
```

and it works, but now I need to send (post) some parameters (as an authorization code, GPS coordinates, user's mail or something similar) into the request to the server to receive a specific JSON. Server is already configured and it works fine, but I can't find a guide to modify my code to do that. Does somebody knows how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of posting data to server using JSON, for example the json is below:

```
NSDictionary *json = @{@"authorization_code": yourAuthorizationCode,@"gps": @{@"lat": latitude,@"lng": longitude},@"email":email};
```

## JSON Posting

Posting on server depends also on your server requirements, so if it requires a JSON to post, this is the way:

```
//Create an AFHTTPRequestOperationManager
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

//Depending if you need a HTTP header, you create one
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
NSString *yourAuthorizationCode;
NSString *latitude;
NSString *longitude;
NSString *email;


//My data to be posted via JSON
NSDictionary *json = @{@"authorization_code": yourAuthorizationCode,@"gps": @{@"lat": latitude,@"lng": longitude},@"email":email};


//Sending Post Method, with parameter JSON
[manager POST:@"http://myphp.com/api/v1/profile" parameters:json success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
 {
     NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
 }
      failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
 {
     NSLog(@"Error at creating post: %@", error);
 }];
```

## Parameters posted via URL

In this method parameters are passed in URL, and you post them to server in URL form

```
//Create an AFHTTPRequestOperationManager
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];


NSString *yourAuthorizationCode;
NSString *latitude;
NSString *longitude;
NSString *email;

//Sending Post Method, with parameter JSON (You can change your method of sending data to server just by replacing POST with GET)
[manager POST:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://myphp.com/api/v1/profile?authorization_code=%@&gps_lat=%@&gps_lng=%@&email=%@",yourAuthorizationCode,latitude,longitude,email] parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
 {
     NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
 }
      failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
 {
     NSLog(@"Error at creating post: %@", error);
 }];
```

Hope it helps, give me feedback!